# функция onTouch() для LinearLayout не работает

Tags: java, android

Есть файл FirstLevel, куда пользователь переходит из меню (mainActivity).
Нужно сделать появление LinearLayout при касании экрана в FirstLevel (LinearLayout состоит из двух TextView, реализован в отдельном XML-файле). Однако приложение вылетает, еще при переходе из mainActivity в FirstLevel.

```java
public class First_level extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    ImageButton firstButton;
    //boolean flag = true;
    String[] replics  = {...}; //заполненные массивы
    String[] who = {...};
    int i = 0;
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_level);
        LinearLayout gameWindow = findViewById(R.id.mesWin);
        gameWindow.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    void npcsay(String text, String hero)
    {
        LinearLayout gameWindow = findViewById(R.id.mesWin);
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message, null);
        TextView username = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        username.setText(hero);
        TextView ttxt = view.findViewById(R.id.point);
        ttxt.setText(text);
        gameWindow.addView(view);
    }


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            npcsay(replics[i], who[i]);
            i++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: `LinearLayout gameWindow = findViewById(R.id.mesWin);` выполняется при создании класса. Все findViewById должны быть строго после выполнения setContentView

Comment: спасибо @IR42 ! теперь приложение не вылетает, но также ничего не происходит при нажатии на экран